# Usage of cloned factory contract pattern for erc721 marketplace contracts

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, erc-721, proxy-contracts

I have an upgradeable ERC721 contract for a marketplace and its working is such that every time a new collection is to be deployed a new contract is created for that collection.
Now, I this process is quiet costly gas wise. So, I want to know that if we use the cloned factory pattern will this also be deploying those same multiple contracts for different collections? What would be the advantages or disadvantages of using this approach?

Comment: Hi @mzaidi please follow up, you have an answer here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage is that you can be confident that the cloned contracts work to the specifications that you set.

Therefore you can delegate to other people to perform the cloning. Or you can automate it.

If, instead, you were the only person that could deploy new contracts then you would always be on the hook for that.

---

Also, please stop using upgradable contracts. Nobody wants that.